# Delete element from Array after use - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, random, swift2

My card is composed of 52 cards, so I created an `array` for them, and when the user click on the screen, a card is revealed.

I want that when a card is pulled, it can no longer be pulled in the future. I used `removeAtIndex` to remove the pulled card from the `array`. The function `pullCard` is called when the user touch the screen anywhere:

```
// Cards
let card1 = (1, "AS", "RULE 1")
let card2 = (2, "2", "RULE 2")
let card3 = (3, "3", "RULE 3")
let card4 = (4, "4", "RULE 4")
let card5... (to 52)

// Array
var cards = [
    card1,
    card2,
    card3,
    card4,
    card5... (to 52)
]

func pullCard() {
    let randomCard = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count)))
    let cardsIndex = randomCard - 1
    let card = cards[cardsIndex]
    cards.removeAtIndex(cardsIndex)
}
```

Per example, the game pull the card 32, so it delete it from the array, and after if the game pull the same card, it crash because the card was deleted.

I tried to use an if statement :

```
if cards[cardsIndex] == nil {
    pullCard()
}
```

But it does not work.
Please help me :)

Comment: Do you mean for your if statement to be `cards[cardsIndex] != nil`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a problem here:

```
let cardsIndex = randomCard - 1
```

It should be:

```
let cardsIndex = randomCard
```

Infact you are generating `randomCard` as a random `Int` between `0` and `(cards.count - 1)`.

So `randomCard` is already a **valid index** for `cards`, there's no need to subtract `1`.
When the random generated number does happen to be `0`, you try to access the index `-1` of `cards` and this is bad in this universe.

*I admit this bug does not match exactly the description you gave in the question but I suggest you to fix it and try again.*

Comment: This should fix the issue.